# check the list of Open window

Tags: shell

I need to know that how can I find the list of open "*windows*" and then close some of them. Note that any window is required meaning that some of the window (like Plot) may be opened during a simulation with a software. I also want to detect them. Imagine that I use a mathematic software and it plot a graph in a new window.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `wmctrl` program.

an example (done with KDE as DE)

```
#list open windows
wmctrl -l
0x01e001a6 -1 HOSTNAME plasma-desktop
0x01e007c1 -1 HOSTNAME plasma-desktop
0x01e00194 -1 HOSTNAME plasma-desktop
0x01e0019d -1 HOSTNAME plasma-desktop
0x03c00064  0 HOSTNAME Inbox - Mozilla Thunderbird
0x0240001a  0 HOSTNAME pam.d : bash – Konsole
0x04e00009  0 HOSTNAME 
0x03e0006e  0 HOSTNAME shell - check the list of Open window - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange - Mozilla Firefox
0x03e6efe3  0 HOSTNAME Mozilla Firefox


#now close the empty firefox session: (-c for close, -i for using the hexnumber of the first column as identifier)
wmctrl -ic 0x03e6efe3
```

You can also use this program for changing window geometries, selecting windows, moving windows, change window titles etc. Check `man wmctrl` for viewing the possibilities.